# AWK\SED Replace both ^(beginning) and $(end) of a string in a single command

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I've been looking around but couldn't find a way to do it with both **AWK** and **SED**. 
I was wondering if there's a way to replace a string's start and end in a single command.

**more specifically**, there's a file with a lot of words in it, and I would like to add something **before** the word and **after** the word.

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you tried with a proper i/p and o/p and the versions of `Awk` , `sed` you have? output of `awk --version` and `sed --version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Since you said:** *more specifically, there's a file with a lot of words in it, and I would like to add something before the word and after the word.*

The only thing you need is `$&` that is match itself. So you simply can write anything that you want just **before** and **end** of this whildcard. that's it.

For example say you have this file:

```
this is line 1.
this is line 2.
this is line 3.
```

And I tested with **perl:**
`perl -lne 'print "beginning->", $&, "<-end" if /.+/g' file`
which the output is:

```
beginning->this is line 1.<-end
beginning->this is line 2.<-end
beginning->this is line 3.<-end
```

---

May you would like to match only one word, so still this is a good solution such as:

```
perl -lne 'use English; print "$PREMATCH", "[$MATCH]","$POSTMATCH" if /line/g' file
```

Here I matched `line` and put around that: `[` then `$&` then `]`
**the output**

```
this is [line] 1.
this is [line] 2.
this is [line] 3.
```

---

**NOTE**
As you can see the only things you need just are **prematch** and **match** and **postmatch**. I tested it with **perl** for you, and if you are interesting in **Perl** you can use it or may you want to use **Sed** or **Awk**. Since you have no specific **examples** I tested with **Perl**.

Comment: I had never seen `use English` before. That is so cool. Thanks for the new thing for today.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap a particular word with markers you can use `&` in the replacement string to achieve what you want.

For example to put square brackets around every occurrence of the word bird:

```
$ echo "hello bird, are you really a bird?" | sed "s/\bbird\b/[&]/g"
hello [bird], are you really a [bird]?
```

Comment: you may want to use `\b`, for example, my text has `thunderbird`

Answer (score 0):

> to replace a string's start and end in a single command

Let's say we have a test file with line:

```
tag hello, world tag
```

To enclose each `tag` word with angle brackets `< ... >` we can apply:

***awk*** approach with `gsub()` function:

```
awk '{ gsub(/\<tag\>/, "<&>"); print}' test_file
```

word boundaries `\<`, `\>` may differ depending on awk implementations

---

***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/\btag\b/<&>/g' test_file
```

The output(for both approaches):

```
<tag> hello, world <tag>
```

Comment: With sed and awk we need not to use cat test_file | awk/sed. awk/sed will be able to read test_file by themselves.